# Python modifying and editing lists

Tags: python, list

I am just starting to learn python, I was trying out some code and I wanted to ask why the two following codes function differently?

**First code sample:**

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  new_list = list2
  index = len(list2)
  for items in list1:
      new_list.insert(index, items)
  return(new_list)
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

The output of this first code is correct (where I want list 1 reversed):

> ['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Peter', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']

**Second code sample:**

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  new_list = list2
  for items in list1:
      new_list.insert(len(list2), items)
  return(new_list)
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

But this second code outputs:

> ['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Alice', 'Cindy', 'Bobby', 'Jan', 'Peter']

Why is there a difference in these two outputs by just assigning the len(list2) to a variable and using that for the index insertion?

Thanks!

Comment: `new_list = list2` doesn't make a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
    new_list = list2
```

Just creates a new name for the `list2` list, but both variables refer to the same list.

So, in the first example, you get the length of that list with `index = len(list2)` and then use the same value for `index` on each iteration through the for loop.

In the second example, you get `len(list2)` for each iteration, but since you're modifying `new_list`, you're also modifying `list2` and its length will increase as you go.

If you need a copy of the list, create a copy with `list(new_list) = list2` or `new_list = list2.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

### First code snippet

---

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  new_list = list2
  index = len(list2)
  for items in list1:
      new_list.insert(index, items)
      print(new_list)
  return(new_list)
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Output:

```
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Alice']
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Peter', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Peter', 'Jan', 'Bobby', 'Cindy', 'Alice']
```

For your first code, you're inserting `new_list.insert(index, items)` every new item on the same position for a certain period `( len(list2) )`. Every time when you insert it get the same index and last insert element get move to the `index+1` position and that's why it seems `Jamies_list` the list are inserting reversely.

### Second code snippet

Since you're allocating `len(list2)` every time of `for loop`, it get dynamically update the `len` and taking the new the position of the new item